# jquery autocomplete with asp.net mvc 5 not populate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, dropdown

I'm trying to write dropdown that can filter result by tying on it. for thatI have used jquery autocomplete.

**Model Class**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller class**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetVisitCustomer(string term = "")
    {

        List<Customer> objCustomerlist = new List<Customer>()
        {

            new Customer {CustomerID=1,CustomerName="Ananda" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=2,CustomerName="Basitha" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=3,CustomerName="Chathura" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=4,CustomerName="Darashana" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=5,CustomerName="Eshan" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=6,CustomerName="Fuzal" },
            new Customer {CustomerID=7,CustomerName="Gihan" }

        };


        var filteCustomers = objCustomerlist
                    .Where(c => c.CustomerName.ToUpper()
                    .Contains(term))
                    .Select(c => new { Name = c.CustomerName, ID = c.CustomerID })
                    .Distinct().ToList();

        return Json(filteCustomers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
}
```

**View class**

```
@model MVC5AutoComplete.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Dropdown";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "Customer")',
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                            return {
                                label: val.Name,
                                value: val.Name,
                                customerId: val.ID
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#CustomerID").val(ui.item.customerId);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CustomerID)
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

This is compiling without any compile time errors.But this is not populate any result on drop-down, I put a debug point on `GetVisitCustomer` that one not even triggering,

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console? (and not related, but since its a POST, it can just be `return Json(filteCustomers);`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can see something like this http://imgur.com/bo3iABX

Comment: now oky its saying `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`

Comment: That suggests that `jquery-ui.js` is not being loaded, or that you have another copy of `jquery-{version}.js` being loaded after `jquery-ui.js`

Answer (score 0):

There may be two places that I think you need to change.

1. Your js code

If you have a layout page (LayOut = Null not set in your view)and jquery-{version}.js is already there in layout page.

- Remove `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` from your code.
- Keep your entire script inside `@section Scripts` like this.

  ```
  @section Scripts {
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      @*<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>*@
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
                  source: function (request, response) {
                      $.ajax({
                          url: '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "Test")',
                          type: "POST",
                          datatype: "json",
                          data: {
                              term: request.term
                          },
                          success: function (data) {
                              response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                                  return {
                                      label: val.Name,
                                      value: val.Name,
                                      customerId: val.ID
                                  }
                              }))
                          }
                      })
                  },
                  select: function (event, ui) {                            
                      $("#CustomerID").val(ui.item.customerId);
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
  }
  ```

  2. Need to change your LINQ expression to get back the proper result.
     change `.Contains(term))` to `.Contains(term.ToUpper()))`
  3. **Most importantly remove all break points and debugger if any related this code.**